# He likes skiing and she loves walking

Tags: gerunds, construction

Can anyone explain to me what you call this type of sentence form in English?
Other examples: she likes skiing -  I like reading - I love cycling - We hate driving ...
It's not a Present Continuous as PC is with the verb 'to be' and the -ing form.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple SVO (subject-verb-object) sentence, just the object is the **gerund**. The gerund is a form of the verb that acts as a noun representing the activity the verb relates to, and as the same form as the progressive participle.